# Expression Blend: Dragging controls from toolbox

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I am following some tutorials with expression blend and many of them are tell me to drag a TextBlock from the toolbox. Sure enough I see it, if I long click on it it displays for additional controls.

So if I click it and drag it it should work but it opens up the other controls.

If I double click it then it places it in my design view but I want to drag and drop it.

Am I missing something here, the tutorials I am following are for Expression Blend 4 and I am using Expression Blend 4.

Thinking about it, its sounds correct that you should be able to drag and drop a control on the design surface, but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in Standard Expression Blend and I assume there is only one version of Expression Blend 4 you actually can't place controls via drag and drop from the toolbox onto the design surface. At least this is my experience.

If you want to place a control what you do is to choose a control via left mouse click in the toolbox which makes it the currently selected one. Then you can place it onto the design surface by defining its dimensions at the place you want to have it positioned.

AFAIK there is no function to drag a control out of the toolbox.

Comment: I call this "Select and Draw".  Remember that you are dealing with a graphics application, so just like you would draw a Rectangle in an application like Paint you will "draw" the selected element where ever you want it.  You can also double-click an element type and it will be added as the next child in the "active container".